# Submit button CSS styling

Tags: html, css, forms

Needing to make my submit button to style like other buttons on the website. Here is the html code:

```
<p><input type='submit' value='Search' class='button'></p>
```

And the css

```
.button:link, .button:active, .button:visited {
background: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
border: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.button:hover {
background: #333333;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333, #000000);
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
border: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The hover effect works fine. But the normal grey box is there when not hovering. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.button:link, .button:active, .button:visited {` with `.button:link, .button:active, .button:visited, .button {`

You have not added a default style for .button itself.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.button{
background: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
border: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.button:hover {
background: #333333;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333, #000000);
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
border: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: worked for the submit button, but voided my other buttons.

Comment: if you have other buttons share the same class,  just follow @Mehul Mohan 's answer. Adding the the other 3 selectors.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-classes `:link`, `:active` and `:visited` are only valid for `<a>` elements, not for `<input>` elements. Use just .`button` for the non-hover state, and it will work.

Comment: Wait, so valid only for Elements, or not for Elements?

Comment: The tags have been filtered, sorry, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sah9hLya/)

You can select the `submit` button as `input[type="submit"]`

```
input[type="submit"]{
    background: red;
}
```

Please read more about **Attribute Selectors** in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

**OR**

You could just use `.button` to style the submit button as it has the class `button`

Thus add the below one to your css

```
.button{
    background: red;
}
```

Please refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sah9hLya/1/)